# database table for scheduling system

Tags: database-schema

Please correct me if I design it wrong. I need to design 3 tables as follow:

1. students : id, name
2. sections : id, student_id, s_name
3. schedules: id, section_id, c_name

And here are requirements:
There are students, and each of those student has sections, and each of those sections has schedule.

- The relationship from students to sections, sections to schedules is 1 to many
- student can have many sections
- section can have only 1 student / section can have many schedules
- schedule can have only 1 section

========= Here are my tables: =====

1. students

   - id         --> primary and auto increment
   - name
2. sections

   - id         --> primary and auto increment
   - student_id --> foreign key reference to id of students table
   - s_name
3. schedules

   - id         --> primary and auto increment
   - section_id --> foreign key reference to id of sections table
   - c_name

I would appreciate any helps and many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your schema seems to be BCNF normalized, but it does not fulfil all the given requirement. I would change a few things to make it more intuitive.

```
2. Sections Table:
section_id -> primary, auto increment
student_id -> Foreign Key to students.id
```

Explanation: Section ID is one to one with student, but student is one to many with section.

```
3. SectionNames Table:
section_id -> primary and foreign key, from section table.
section_name -> String, name of section.
```

Explanation : You would add this if you need to store s_name, like you're doing right now.

```
4. Schedule Table:
class_id -> Primary, auto increment key
section_id -> Foreign key, sections table.
```

Explanation: Schedule's (Class's) one to one relation to section, and sections one to many relation to classes.

```
5. ScheduleName Table:
class_id -> Primary, and foreign key to schedule table.
class_name -> String
```

Explanation: Stores c_name as per your table schema.